# Sending embeds with JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm trying to make command "help" that will send all bot commands in embed message, but `event.channel().sendMessage(eb.build()).queue();` don't work.
**Full Code of command:**

```
    if (event.getAuthor().isBot()) return;

    MessageChannel channel = event.getChannel();
    String message = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();
    String name = event.getAuthor().getName();

    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase(">help")) {
        EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder();

        eb.setColor(0x26FF00);
        eb.setTitle("Commands");
        eb.setDescription("Command test...");
        eb.setFooter("Made by kersozone.pl");
        event.getChannel().sendMessage((CharSequence) eb.build()).queue();
    }
```

`

I tried adding`(CharSequence)`, but command still don't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [sendMessageEmbeds](https://docs.jda.wiki/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/channel/middleman/MessageChannel.html#sendMessageEmbeds(net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.MessageEmbed,net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.MessageEmbed...)).